# smart pointer deletion in C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I was reading the smart pointer implementation in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smart-pointers-cpp/), everything works well as the example indicated. However, if i try to upcasting an object pointer and use the smart pointer, then there will be a runtime error complaint about the object been freed is not allocated, can someone please tell me what happened and how to fix it? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class SmartPointer{
    T* ptr = nullptr;
public:
    explicit SmartPointer(T* t):ptr(t){}
     virtual ~SmartPointer(){
        std::cout<<"call delete here"<<std::endl;
        if (ptr!=NULL){
            delete (ptr);
        }
    }
    T & operator*(){
        return *ptr;
    }
    T * operator->(){
        return ptr;
    }

};



class Animal{
public:
    virtual void get_name(){};
    virtual ~Animal(){std::cout<<"animal is destroied"<<std::endl;}
};



class Dog:public Animal{
    std::string d_name;
public:
    Dog(std::string n):d_name(n){}
    virtual ~Dog(){std::cout<<"dog is destroied"<<std::endl;}
    void get_name(){std::cout<<"the name is "<<d_name<<std::endl;}
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// These lines will work
    SmartPointer<Animal>smt_animal_pt(new Animal);

// These lines will not work
    //    SmartPointer<Animal>smt_animal_pt(new Animal());
    //    Dog d("Dean");
    //    smt_animal_pt = &d;
    //    smt_animal_pt->get_name();

// These lines will not work as well
//        Animal *a = new Animal;
//        Dog d("Dean");
//        a = &d;
//        SmartPointer<Animal>smt_animal_pt(a);
//        smt_animal_pt->get_name();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger and check it out.

Comment: Why do you think it should work to call delete on a pointer to a local stack variable?

Comment: Why are you not just using `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` & `std::weak_ptr`? They already exist and do all you need..

Comment: Don't worry about smart pointers until you have understood at least the fundamentals about dumb pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental issue you are having is that you are assigning the smart pointer to point at [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) memory rather than [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) memory. Stack memory will be free'd when it leaves scope, where as heap memory is only free'd by an invocation of `delete` (or `delete[]`, or `free()` depending on how it was allocated).

You should only assign your smart pointer to memory allocated with `new`.